Where to find good English translations of Jewish Texts like Yalkut Shimoni?
I’m interested in gaining access to Jewish texts like the Yalkut Shimoni. I’ve seen interesting excerpts translated, like 499 concerning the light of creation being the soul of the Messiah and I’d love to see what else is in there. Unfortunately, the Sefaria app appears to only provide the text in Hebrew and I haven’t found a translation via Google yet…
Long term I know I’m gonna have to learn Hebrew - but if there are any good English resources you could point me towards I’d appreciate it.

Yalkut Shimoni is a compilation of older midrashim. Most of them are extant in another collection. Following the sources should usually lead to the original source, often with a translation available. For instance, the text you quoted (from Yalkut Shimoni 2:499) is quoted from Pesikta Rabbati (cited in footnote 61; the source is chapter 36). Pesikta Rabbati is in turn available in at least two English translations (William Braude and Rivka Ulmer).

Thank you! Unfortunately since it’s all Hebrew I can’t figure out what the sources are myself right now :P I took a couple courses in Hebrew back in college but never got it to a functional level. I’ll need to pick it back up again
